# Cannot add Push Notifications Capability in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

Whenever I try to add the Push Notifications Capability it either does not get added afterwards or Xcode (v. 12.5) even crashes. Had anyone else a similar problem and could solve it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the issue by myself - make sure CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS in the build settings are empty before you add the capability.

I used [XcodeGen](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen) for creating my project by copy-pasting an other one and was missing that the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS were already filled then. This somehow caused the problem that I could not add the capability anymore.